# Why are argument names required for function calls, and not allowed for functions assigned to variables?

Tags: swift, function, syntax, arguments

If I have the following code, why am I not required to use the argument names in the function call and instead an error is thrown when I attempt to add them?

```swift
func foo(bar: Any) {}
var faz = foo

foo(1) // Missing argument label 'bar:' in call
foo(bar: 1)
faz(1)
faz(bar: 1) // Extraneous argument label 'bar:' in call
```

Answer (score 4):

When you assign your method as closure, you just assign method's types of paramters and return type, so type of your closure is actually `(Types of arguments) -> Return type`

In your specific case: `(Any) -> Void`

As you can see, this closure doesn't have names for arguments and you can't add them. So adding argument label when you call your closure won't work.

But, you can name parameter which closure takes when you declare it and then you can work with it inside closure scope ... similar to declaring function

```
faz = { bar in 
    ... // you can work with bar of type `Any`
}
```